# Getting error when trying to insert element in a sorted array

Tags: java

I am trying to add an element in an array and then sorting it. But when I try to insert element again in a sorted array, that time it's showing me an array. Please help me for how to insert an element in a sorted array.

My code is right below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InsertionSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n, temp, i, count = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of Elements");
        n = s.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter all the elements");

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = s.nextInt();
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Ascending Order is :");

        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
        }

        System.out.println(a[n - 1]);
        System.out.println("Select the number which you want to delete : ");
        int del = s.nextInt();

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (a[i] == del) {
                for (int j = i; j < (n - 1); j++) {
                    a[j] = a[j + 1];
                }

                count++;
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.print("\nNow the New Array is :\n");

        for (i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println("Write a number which you want to insert :");

        int insert = s.nextInt();

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (insert > a[j]) {
                    temp = insert;
                    insert = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Ascending Order is :");
        System.out.print(insert + ",");     
        System.out.println(a[n + 1]);
    }   
}
```

till adding elements and deleting is working properly but inserting new element is not working properly.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Do you have an issue with inserting or deleting and exactly what is the issue?

Comment: I edited the code, the array which I am getting is array out of bound.

Comment: After having deleted an element, you should decrease `n` since the array has 1 less entry.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void insertIntoSortedArray(int[] arrSorted, int val) {
    int i = 0;

    // find insert position - i
    while (i < arrSorted.length - 1 && arrSorted[i] < val) {
        i++;
    }

    // shift array 1 position right (ignore last element)
    if (i < arrSorted.length - 1)
        System.arraycopy(arrSorted, i, arrSorted, i + 1, arrSorted.length - i - 1);

    // insert 1 element
    arrSorted[i] = val;
}
```

**Demo:**

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 };
insertIntoSortedArray(arr, 4);  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
insertIntoSortedArray(arr, 7);  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
insertIntoSortedArray(arr, -1); // [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your code is causing the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
System.out.println(a[n + 1]);
```

It should be something else like

```
System.out.println(a[j + 1]);
```

or whatever you like to print, maybe the entire array?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a[n+1], try a[n-1], that is where you are getting out of bound exception

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in last string. Your last index in array is **n-1**. 
[Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) Chapter 10.4

Answer (score 0):

following line is causing error;

`System.out.println(a[n + 1])`

instead write;

```
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        System.out.println(a[k]);
```

by adding code above, your error(`ArrayIndexOutOfBound`) will be solved and code will work, but there is logical error in your code that resultant array is not correctly sorted. Which you've to solve. :)